# Can't do the command 'rails console' (error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I type 'rails console' in my website folder i get following error :

```
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6090:in `delete': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6090:in `alloc_history_entry'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6123:in `add_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/readline.rb:368:in `<<'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `each'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block in load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `open'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:65:in `extended'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `extend'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `init_save_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:45:in `save_history='
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `new'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `initialize'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:383:in `new'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:383:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:62:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:17:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:97:in `perform'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have Rails version 5.1.4, ruby 2.3.3 and installed it with this tutorial : http://installrails.com/steps/railsinstaller_windows

How can I fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Ruby version 2.3.3 @MarekLipka

Comment: have you tried rake rails:update:bin ?

Comment: and what's happen when you type ``bundle update``?

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati It write don't know how to build task rails:update:bin

Comment: @RonanLouarn It update everything and it write bundle updated! at the end. After this the rails console command does the same error